# mix-blend-mode Property in parent element but not desired in child element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a photo with an outline that uses mix-blend-mode on the outline only. I am attempting this by using a background div to simulate an outline and stack my image on top of it. However, I am not sure how to have the child use a normal mix-blend-mode while the parent uses color-burn.

I tried to use the `isolation: isolate` property on the child with no success. Here is a code snippet to show the issue:

index.html:

```html
<div id="headshot-container">`
    <div id="headshot-outline">
        <img src="img/headshot.jpeg" alt="" id="headshot">
    </div>
</div>
```

main.css:

```css
#headshot {
    z-index: 2;
    isolation: isolate;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    mix-blend-mode: normal;
}

#headshot-outline {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #555;
    mix-blend-mode: color-burn;
}
```